# How to permanently validate google captcha for sending email smtp in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, developer-tools, google-developers-console

I have created Rails 6 application with ruby 2.6.5. Using SMTP for sending emails.
Added configurations in config/environment/*rb file.

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  user_name:      ENV['SENDMAIL_USERNAME'],
  password:       ENV['SENDMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  domain:         ENV['MAIL_HOST'],
  address:       'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:          '587',
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Getting Error: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtOS
After Verifiying captcha from the below link

```
[https://accounts.google.com/b/1/DisplayUnlockCaptcha][1]
```

It work for some time than again it start throwing the same error.
I have enabled less secure apps also for my email.

Answer (score 0):

It is common issue i used to get when using action mailer with google SMTP configuration. I used to fellow below few step to solve it.

1. Try to login to google account manually with same location where rails server is there and check if captcha is showing.
2. Once Mail working from rails sever never login manually to goole account again.
3. Try changing  authentication: :plain to :login